# Is there a fool proof way to change the clock position on my lockscreen? Nothing else. Just drop it down by 50 pixels

Tags: lock-screens, android-12, oneplus

Title says it all:
Is it possible to change the position of the clock on the lockscreen.
I need to move it downwards a bit.

I'm on a OnePlus 8 (IN2015_11_C.21)

Latest Android (12)

Comment: Since the clock on the native lock screen is baked into the system, I'm not sure if there's a way unless with a root (code injection wizardry) or a 3rd-party lock screen app.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT.